# How do I clear the editor in Slatejs v0.50+?

Tags: javascript, slatejs

I can't figure out how to delete everything in the editor in Slate v0.50+.

I used to be able to do something like this:

```js
editor.moveToRangeOfDocument().delete()
```

How do I do this now?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to first get the start `Location` of the editor, then the end `Location`, and finally use `Transforms.delete`, like this:

```js
import { Transforms } from 'slate';

// ...

Transforms.delete(editor, {
  at: {
    anchor: Editor.start(editor, []),
    focus: Editor.end(editor, []),
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only thing that worked for me..